# Clear manual mock jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am using manual mock for a module. I want to clear a mocked function in the manual mock and mock return a new value for it. How can I do that? I tried many ways but it always returned value in manual mock.
I use `jest.clearAllMocks()` and `jest.resetAllMocks()` in beforeEach and use `mockReturnValue` to mock new value for that function but it doesn't change.
This is my manual mock

```
const firebase = {};
firebase.storage = {
  bucket: jest.fn(),
  upload: jest
    .fn()
    .mockResolvedValue([
      { getSignedUrl: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(["link"]) }
    ]),
  file: _ => ({
    delete: jest.fn()
  })
};
module.exports = firebase;
```

I get value `link` but I can't mock other values in my unit test

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. *I tried many ways* - what did you try?

Comment: It depends how you "manual mock" is implemented. Jest calls them "manual mocks" but they are not really mocks, they are fakes, i.e. alternative implementations. If yours is not implemented using the mocking functions provided by Jest (`jest.fn()` f.e.) calling `jest.clearAllMocks()` and `jest.resetAllMocks()` does not have any effect on it.

Comment: I know. If I mock return value in manual mocks, I can get a value in functions I call that mocks. When I use clearAllMocks and mock new value in unit test. It still uses old value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use one of this a the specific mock:

- [`mockFn.mockClear()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear): will remove all stored information about calling the mock
- [`mockFn.mockRestore()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore): same above plus removing the mocked return values
- [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn): set a new return value for the mock

There are 2 ways to create the mockFn instance either:

```
const mockFn = jest.fn()
```

or by importing a mock:

```
import mockFn from 'mockedModule'
jest.mock('mockedModule', ()=> jest.fn())
```